# Next step in form does not render

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I've been trying to split my questions into "pages" to render different groups of inputs, between the first och the second question it works. But going from the second to the third question I get an error.

Can someone with fresher eyes see what is going wrong?

I am a newbie to React, just learning and assume that I have missed one thing or two.

```
ERROR: ----> index.js:1 Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it. in QuestionStageArtRadio (at Form.js:86) in div (at Form.js:85) in form (at Form.js:60) in section (at Form.js:58) in Form (at App.js:11) in main (at App.js:10) in App (at src/index.js:6) 

CODE

Form.js
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
const Form = () => {
  const [page, setPage] = useState(0)
  const [showSummary, setShowSummary] = useState(false)
  const [inhabitants, setInhabitants] = useState('') 
  const [ageCategory, setAgeCategory] = useState('') 
  const [stageArtCategory, setStageArtCategory] = useState('')

const onPageChange = (pagenumber) => {
    setPage(pagenumber)
  }

const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setShowSummary(true)
  }

return (
    <section className="form-container">
      {!showSummary ? (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>

        {page === 0 && ( 
            <div>
            <QuestionCitySelect
              inhabitants={inhabitants}
              setInhabitants={setInhabitants}
              page={page}
              setPage={onPageChange}
            />
            </div>
        )}

        {page === 1 && (
            <div>
            <QuestionAgeRadio
              ageCategory={ageCategory}
              setAgeCategory={setAgeCategory}
              page={page}
              setPage={onPageChange}
            />
            </div>
        )}

        {page === 2 && (
            <div>
            <QuestionStageArtRadio
              stageArtCategory={stageArtCategory}
              setStageArtCategory={setStageArtCategory}
              page={page}
              setPage={onPageChange}
            />
            </div>
        )}

..and so forth.....
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
QuestionStageArtRadio (the third question)
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
import React from 'react'

import NextQuestionButton from './NextQuestionButton'

const QuestionStageArtRadio = () => ({
  stageArtCategory,
  setStageArtCategory,
  page,
  setPage,
  onNextQuestion,
  message
}) => {
  const onStageArtChange = (e) => {
    setStageArtCategory(e.target.value)
  }

  const stageart = ["I'm for experimental shit, I need to see something I can not immediately understand", "I want to dance with my kid", "Opera", "Theatre", "Musical", "I just miss the feeling of collectivity, and long to be able to see something with another person's eye - just once, please!", "Concert"]

  return (
    <article className="form-question">
      {/* Question */}
      <p htmlFor="stage" className="form-question" tabIndex="0">
        What kind of stage art would you like too experience post Covid-19?
      </p>

      {/* Answer */}
      <div className="question-content-container">
        {stageart.map((stagetype) => (
          <span key={stagetype} className="form-radiobuttons">
            <input
              name="stagetype"
              id={stagetype}
              type="radio"
              onChange={onStageArtChange}
              //checked={stageArtCategory === category}
              className="form-radiobuttons"
            />
            <label htmlFor={stagetype} aria-label={stagetype} tabIndex="0">
              <span className="form-radiobutton-input">{stagetype}</span>
            </label>
          </span>
        ))}
      </div>
      <div className="buttons-container">
        <NextQuestionButton
          page={page}
          setPage={setPage}
          currentState={stageArtCategory}
          defaultState=""
          message="Please choose what kind of stage art you would like to experience"
          onClick={onNextQuestion}
        />
      </div>
    </article>
  )
}

export default QuestionStageArtRadio

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
NextQuestionButton.js
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
import React from 'react'

const NextQuestionButton = ({
  page,
  setPage,
  message
}) => {
  const onNextQuestion = () => setPage(page +1)

  return (
    <>
      <button
        type="button"
        aria-label="button to the next question"
        className="next-button"
        onClick={onNextQuestion}
        message={message}
      >
        Next question
      </button>
    </>
  )
}
export default NextQuestionButton
```

Comment: Can you show what kind of error you got ?

Comment: @Caroline: it is best to add additional information to the original post rather than posting it in a comment. Often, users will not read the entire comment tree and miss this additional information. Please consider adding it to the OP.

Comment: @DaveL17 Thank you for pointing that out. I will add it to the OP instead.

Comment: @ Caroline NP!  Thanks for contributing to SO with your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have wrong syntax with your QuestionStageArtRadio, you have function which return function which return component.

Remove brackets changing this:

```
const QuestionStageArtRadio = () => ({ /* props */ }) => <div/>
```

into this:

```
const QuestionStageArtRadio = ({ /* props */ }) => <div/>
```

Comment: Thank you!! Fresh eyes needed!